# Initial value problem for a system of ODEs solver C program

Tags: c, differential-equations

So I wanted to implement the path of the Moon around the Earth with a C program.
My problem is that you know the Moon's velocity and position at Apogee and Perigee.
So I started to solve it from Apogee, but I cannot figure out how I could add the second velocity and position as "initial value" for it. I tried it with an `if` but I don't see any difference between the results. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef void (*ode)(double* p, double t, double* k, double* dk);

void euler(ode f, double *p, double t, double* k, double h, int n, int N)
{
    double kn[N];
    double dk[N];
    double Rp = - 3.633 * pow(10,8); // x position at Perigee

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        f(p, 0, k, dk);
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (k[0] == Rp)     // this is the "if" I mentioned in my comment
                                // x coordinate at Perigee
            {                    
                k[1] = 0;   // y coordinate at Perigee
                k[2] = 0;   // x velocity component at Perigee
                k[3] = 1076; // y velocity component at Perigee
            }
            kn[j] = k[j] + h * dk[j];
            printf("%f ", kn[j]);
            k[j] = kn[j];
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void gravity_equation(double* p, double t, double* k, double* dk)
{
    // Earth is at the (0, 0)

    double G = p[0]; // Gravitational constant
    double m = p[1]; // Earth mass
    double x = k[0]; // x coordinate at Apogee
    double y = k[1]; // y coordinate at Apogee
    double Vx = k[2]; // x velocity component at Apogee
    double Vy = k[3]; // y velocity component at Apogee
    dk[0] = Vx;
    dk[1] = Vy;
    dk[2] = (- G * m * x) / pow(sqrt((x * x)+(y * y)),3);
    dk[3] = (- G * m * y) / pow(sqrt((x * x)+(y * y)),3);

}

void run_gravity_equation()
{
    int N = 4;  // how many equations there are

    double initial_values[N];
    initial_values[0] = 4.055*pow(10,8); // x position at Apogee
    initial_values[1] = 0; // y position at Apogee
    initial_values[2] = 0; // x velocity component at Apogee
    initial_values[3] = (-1) * 964; //y velocity component at Perigee

    int p = 2; // how many parameters there are

    double parameters[p];
    parameters[0] = 6.67384 * pow(10, -11); // Gravitational constant
    parameters[1] = 5.9736 * pow(10, 24); // Earth mass


    double h = 3600; // step size
    int n = 3000; // the number of steps

    euler(&gravity_equation, parameters, 0, initial_values, h, n, N);
}

int main()
{
    run_gravity_equation();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `- 3.633 * pow(10, 8)` is better written as `-3.633e8` in C!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I haven't known it until now! Thank you!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Actually in any language supporting floating point literals. Including pocket calculators used in every school.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite well I wouldn't go *that* far ;) But yes, in C, C++, Java, C#, D, Python, Perl, Ruby, JavaScript, Basic, Scala, Clojure, Common Lisp, Scheme, Prolog at least.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Add XML, Pascal, Modula, Delphi, Oberon, Ada, VHDL to the list. Waiting for more ;-)

Comment: XML does not specify a floating point format per se. But JSON does. And YAML. @LeventeGáll so now you know ;)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53650879/3088138 on why the Euler method is really bad in orbital simulations.

Answer (score 2):

Your interface is

```
euler(odefun, params, t0, y0, h, n, N)
```

where

```
N = dimension of state space
n = number of steps to perform
h = step size
t0, y0 = initial time and value
```

The intended function of this procedure seems to be that the updated values are returned inside the array `y0`. There is no reason to insert some hack to force the state to have some initial conditions. The initial condition is passed as argument. As you are doing in `void run_gravity_equation()`. The integration routine should remain agnostic of the details of the physical model.

It is extremely improbable that you will hit the same value in `k[0] == Rp` a second time. What you can do is to check for sign changes in `Vx`, that is, `k[1]` to find points or segments of extremal `x` coordinate.

---

Trying to interpret your description closer, what you want to do is to solve a boundary value problem where `x(0)=4.055e8`, `x'(0)=0`, `y'(0)=-964` and `x(T)=-3.633e8`, `x'(T)=0`. This has the advanced tasks to solve a boundary value problem with single or multiple shooting and additionally, that the upper boundary is variable.

---

You might want to to use the **Kepler laws** to get further insights into the parameters of this problem so that you can solve it just with a forward integration. The Kepler ellipse of the **first Kepler law** has the formula (scaled for Apogee at `phi=0`, Perigee at `phi=pi`)

```
 r = R/(1-E*cos(phi))
```

so that

```
R/(1-E)=4.055e8  and  R/(1+E)=3.633e8,
```

which gives

```
R=3.633*(1+E)=4.055*(1-E)  
==>  E = (4.055-3.633)/(4.055+3.633) = 0.054891,
     R = 3.633e8*(1+0.05489)           = 3.8324e8
```

Further, the angular velocity is given by the **second Kepler law**

```
phi'*r^2 = const. = sqrt(R*G*m)
```

which gives tangential velocities at Apogee (`r=R/(1-E)`)

```
y'(0)=phi'*r = sqrt(R*G*m)*(1-E)/R =  963.9438
```

and Perigee (`r=R/(1+E)`)

```
-y'(T)=phi'*r = sqrt(R*G*m)*(1+E)/R = 1075.9130
```

which indeed reproduces the constants you used in your code.

The area of the Kepler ellipse is `pi/4` times the product of smallest and largest diameter. The smallest diameter can be found at `cos(phi)=E`, the largest is the sum of apogee and perigee radius, so that the area is

```
pi*R/sqrt(1-E^2)*(R/(1+E)+R/(1-E))/2= pi*R^2/(1-E^2)^1.5
```

At the same time it is the integral over `0.5*phi*r^2` over the full period `2*T`, thus equal to

```
sqrt(R*G*m)*T
```

which is the **third Kepler law**. This allows to compute the half-period as

```
T = pi/sqrt(G*m)*(R/(1-E^2))^1.5 = 1185821
```

With `h = 3600` the half point should be reached between `n=329` and `n=330` (`n=329.395`). Integration with `scipy.integrate.odeint` vs. Euler steps gives the following table for `h=3600`:

```
 n      [ x[n], y[n] ] for odeint/lsode              for Euler

 328  [ -4.05469444e+08,   4.83941626e+06]    [ -4.28090166e+08,   3.81898023e+07]
 329  [ -4.05497554e+08,   1.36933874e+06]    [ -4.28507841e+08,   3.48454695e+07]
 330  [ -4.05494242e+08,  -2.10084488e+06]    [ -4.28897657e+08,   3.14986514e+07]
```

The same for `h=36`, `n=32939..32940`

```
 n      [ x[n], y[n] ] for odeint/lsode              for Euler

32938 [ -4.05499997e+08   5.06668940e+04]    [ -4.05754415e+08   3.93845978e+05]
32939 [ -4.05500000e+08   1.59649309e+04]    [ -4.05754462e+08   3.59155385e+05]
32940 [ -4.05500000e+08  -1.87370323e+04]    [ -4.05754505e+08   3.24464789e+05]
32941 [ -4.05499996e+08  -5.34389954e+04]    [ -4.05754545e+08   2.89774191e+05]
```

which is a little closer for the Euler method, but not much better.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful! :) For now, everything is clear!